# Android Studio can't find some resources after internet disconnected

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, resources

So I am having a bit of trouble related to some resource images which stops me to develop the code. My code was working just fine, but after a few minutes without internet, somehow, Android Studio gave me an error, and it could not find 3 resources files anymore:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]
C:\Users\...\Dropbox\programacao\Guia-do-Aluno-UnB\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:(99, 26) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ic_directions_car_black_24dp').
Error:(109, 26) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ic_directions_bike_black_24dp').
Error:(118, 26) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ic_directions_walk_black_24dp').
C:\Users\...\Dropbox\programacao\Guia-do-Aluno-UnB\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:(99, 26) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ic_directions_car_black_24dp').
Error:(109, 26) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ic_directions_bike_black_24dp').
Error:(118, 26) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ic_directions_walk_black_24dp').
```

Here is the execution error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

I have tried:

- Checked the +id
- Cleaned and rebuilt the project
- ReSync the Gradle and build it
- Run as Adminstrator
- Made a clean install
- Changed compileSdkVersion

[Here is an image of the file structure with the error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EOoj.png)

I can't build the project or run it anymore! Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found an answer, instead I have got my backup file and redid the whole code again, as I found no answer.